# Can we generate Control flow graph of the c program by Turbo C compiler?

Tags: c, code-analysis

Can we generate Control flow graph of the c program by Turbo C compiler?

I want to know that there is something given by the compiler to generate a CFG of a C program.

Comment: I think you have it the other way around. Your code should be based on the flow diagrams in your spec. (You do have a spec, right? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think Turbo C has this feature.

Though, modern IDEs have capabilities to draw Class Diagrams, but I personally haven't seen any IDEs drawing Flow diagrams.

**Edit:**

*[Here](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/downloads/code_to_flowchart_software/) is a list of tools that does what you want to achieve.*

Comment: "Modern" IDEs have *all kinds of features* that 20-year-old ones don't have. I suspect you'd be so preoccupied that you wouldn't notice the absence of flow diagrams.

Comment: The link is dead!

Answer (score 0):

CoFlo Can be helpful.
http://coflo.sourceforge.net/wordpress/